# How to apply style for WPF DATAGRID Scrollbars

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid control. I want to apply style for scrollbars. It would be nice if u can give me an example for it.

Thanx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about something this?

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>                                        
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: How would you apply an existing Scrollbar style to the DataGrid Scrollbar?

Comment: Maybe do something like this but put the existing style in the BasedOn attribute of the style

Comment: One important thing to know ... is that the default style for the DataGrid specifies a ScrollViewer template. Therefore, you can't simply style the ScrollViewer ... you need to style the ScrollBar ... or you need to redo the template for the DataGrid and its inherent ScrollViewer template.

Comment: @cplotts Thanks. Confirmed accidentally. `ScrollBar` works, `ScrollViewer` not.